# How to convert a given string to an immutable list of characters in java? [Updated]

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-9, java-16

I am looking for a solution to convert a given string *for example: “helloworld”* to a list of characters which should be immutable in nature.

What I already tried is using **StreamApi**
`'Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())'`
however this results in a ***mutable*** list (not immutable one)

*Any help appreciated!*

Comment: While self-answered questions are very welcome on SO, the question on its own should also match the quality guidelines of SO and yours doesn't (basically it's just a title and a "hook"). Can you [edit] it to turn it into an example of the kinds of questions you'd want this to answer instead?

Comment: Starting with Java 10 there is `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()`

Comment: @greg-449 that’s a waste of time; this question is an artificial problem constructed around the already existing answer. See [the first version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73816623/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have ended up with one of the approach below in order to convert a given string into an immutable list of characters.**

Here, I have used some utility methods as follows:

- **chars()** method available from **java 9** onwards which will convert the given string to int stream.
- **mapToObj()** is an **intermediate operation** which will convert the int stream to char stream.
- **toList()** is a utility method available from **java    16** onwards it will collect the stream to a list which is    **immutable
  in nature.**

*The code snippet shown as below:*

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "helloworld";
            List<Character> list = str.chars().mapToObj(x -> (char)x).toList();
            System.out.println(list);
        }
}
```

**Output:**  `[h, e, l, l, o, w, o, r, l, d]`

**Note :**
*As the list is immutable in nature*, if we try to **modify the list(add/remove operation)**, will get an **exception** as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.add(ImmutableCollections.java:147)
```

**Bonus Points:**

1. During this problem, I have found the difference between
   Stream.collect(Collectors.toList()) and Stream.toList() i.e.

   **Stream.collect(Collectors.toList()) :** It will collect the data
   in a mutable list.

   **Stream.toList() :** It will collect the data in an
   immutable list.
2. The Sonarlint in IDE will also check if there is no operation
   related with the modification of the list, it will prompt with a
   suggestion to

   *Replace the usage of 'Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())'
   with 'Stream.toList()'*

Comment: `chars()` does already exist in Java 8.